# Navision Demo project AL-code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, extends, navision

I 'm using Visual Studio Code 1.16.1 with extension AL Language Extension "0.9.12794". Using  "AL:Go!" im creating a default project with a code example.
I've configured both app.sjon and launch.json and downloaden the symbol files "Microsoft_System_11.0.12925.0" and "Microsoft_W1_11.0.18344.0". Looking at the "Hello World" code example the compiler is unable to find any extends like "Cusomer List" shown below. Showing message "The target Page "Item List" for the extension object is not found"

pageextension 50100 CustomerListExt extends "Customer List"
{
    trigger OnOpenPage();
    begin
        Message('App published: Hello world');
    end;
}

I've checkd the Default settings which are pointing at the correct symbol directoy:

// Sets the diretory path where reference symbol packages are located
  "al.packageCachePath": "./.alpackages",

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot view the Customer list page because you don't have the user permissions.

Check if the Customer List page is within the object range in the app.json file.

for example:

```
"idRange": {
        "from": 1,
        "to": 100000
```